# how to output content of array into table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have any array and I want to first sort it by filenames alphabetically then output the result into the table.

I have created the array successfully but don't know how to sort and output the result into the table. My current code doesn't output anything into table but console.log shows data of array! hope some one help me fix this problems.Thanks

**error on f12**:JSON.parse: unexpected character

This is how I create the array:

```
files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });
```

array structure in console.log output:

```
Object { url="http://someurl.com", filename="new file"},.......
```

javascript function:

```
function displayArray(files){ 
alert(files.length);
console.log(files);


var txt = files;

var files = $.parseJSON( txt ).files;

var $table = $( "<table></table>" );

for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    var emp = files[i];
    var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( emp.url ) );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( emp.filename ) );
    $table.append( $line );
}

$table.appendTo(document.body);


};
```

Comment: `txt ` contains invalid JSON. Are you sure you need to call `$.parseJSON` on it and it's not already a JavaScript array?

Comment: I think you just need to remove `$.parseJSON`

Comment: You don't have JSON, you have an array of object. JSON is a string.

Comment: thanks for replies. That fixed the problem . But why for some array data i get two array data in one table cell? How i can sort before i print ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - This is not dealing with a string though, as your duplicate closure suggests. I am reopning this. It is more than likely a duplicate of another post, just not that one.

Comment: @user1788736 - Search for sorting with a complex object. It has already been posted on exhaustively here.

Comment: sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/1026459